# Why is the “Create New Template” button in Code Workbook greyed out?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-workbooks

The button "Create new template" for a Code Workbook SQL node is greyed out but there's no explanation as to why. Is it because this functionality doesn't exist for SQL?

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. Templates are not supported for SQL nodes.